# android: delete files - ordering of codes

Tags: android, file, view

I would like to ask a question that relates to the ordering of codes.

I am working on a drawing app of which letting user to select image, and then crop the image so as to fit to a drawing plate. Everything works fine using the below code if do not delete the `tempFile` shown in the code:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);      

        if (requestCode == PHOTO_PICKED && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            if (data == null) 
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Null data, but RESULT_OK, from image picker!");
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_photo_picked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
                return;
            }

            if (data != null) 
            {
                    File tempFile = getTempFile();
                    String filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/"+TEMP_PHOTO_FILE;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "path "+filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    doodleView.load_pic(filePath);
//                    if (tempFile.exists()) tempFile.delete();              
            }       
        }
```

The drawing plate is an extended view named doodleView, and would load the cropped chosen image using `doodleView.load_pic(filePath);` I would also like to remove the tempFile after it is used as these are redundant.  Yet if i add `if (tempFile.exists()) tempFile.delete();` the program will crash as the File is deleted before the image file is loaded to the extended view.

If then how could it be rearranged? Or is it possible to execute such delete tempFile on extended View? All the main operations of cropping and placing the tempfile is written in MainActivity.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: what the type of doodleView ? it will be possible to add a listener to load_pic method to inform when charging is finished.

Comment: doodleView is an extended View of the main activity, and is registered in Main activity using doodleView = (DoodleView) findViewById(R.id.doodleView);

Comment: Is there a save button ? You can delete temporary data there.

Comment: if the code is in load_pic method in Thread. this error is normal, then we should add a listener (callback) to inform the caller that the loading is finished.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your advices =) I at first is stuck at the tempfile and overlook there is a filepath transferred to the doodleView class. With the filepath i then simply File file = new File(picturePath);
    file.delete();  anyway...thanks for all your advice!